# Email template center align text next to logo

Tags: html-email

I am creating the header shown below for an email template. As you can see, the text is slightly offset from the center of the email. This happens because I have two table cells: one for the logo and another for the text. I can center the text within its cell, but that cell isn't 100% of the width due to the the logo cell taking up 74 pixels. I can shift the header to the left using `margin-left` in most email clients, but Outlook and Gmail both don't support margins, and I need to support both clients. How can I go about getting the text centered in Outlook and Gmail?

[image]

```
<body style="padding:0; margin:0">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-top: 25px;" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height:76px;" width="600px" class="100p">
          <tr>
            <td background="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sheldon-welcome-email/header.png" bgcolor="#39B491" width="600px" valign="top" class="100p">
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:76px;">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sheldon-welcome-email/header.png" color="#39B491" />
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
              <![endif]-->
              <div>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="100p">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="74px" align="center" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                      <div style="width:44px">
                        <img src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sheldon-welcome-email/my-id-care-logo.png" height="52px" width="44px" class="100p" />
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="*%" align="center">
                      <h3 style="color: white; font-size: 14px; margin: 0px; margin-left: -44px; margin-top: 10px; padding: 0px;"><font face="'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif">Welcome to MyIDCare</font></h3>
                      <h1 style="color: white; font-size: 20px; margin: 0px; margin-left: -44px; padding: 0px;"><font face="'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif">LET'S GET STARTED</font></h1>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
              </v:rect>
              <![endif]-->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a little while to understand your question but i think i got it. You want to center the text within the outer table regardless of the logo being there, right? If thats a yes, then its just a matter of adding another 74px block on the right of the text.

Have a look at the code to see what i did:

```html
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-top: 25px;" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height:76px;" width="600px" class="100p">
          <tr>
            <td background="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sheldon-welcome-email/header.png" bgcolor="#39B491" width="600px" valign="top" class="100p">
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:76px;">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sheldon-welcome-email/header.png" color="#39B491" />
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
              <![endif]-->
              <div>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="100p">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="74px" align="center" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                      <div style="width:44px">
                        <img src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sheldon-welcome-email/my-id-care-logo.png" height="52px" width="44px" class="100p" />
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="*%" align="center">
                      <h3 style="color: white; font-size: 14px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 10px; padding: 0px;"><font face="'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif">Welcome to MyIDCare</font></h3>
                      <h1 style="color: white; font-size: 20px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><font face="'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif">LET'S GET STARTED</font></h1>
                    </td>
                    <td width="74px" align="center">&nbsp;
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
              </v:rect>
              <![endif]-->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Cheers

Comment: Yeah this is a good solution! I added a `&nbsp;` the last table cell, since some clients collapse empty table cells. But this is a solid technique.

Comment: I had removed the nbsp on purpose actually. If one of the td's has content the others will be with its height.